# Count Characters Including the Break Line of an HTML TAG

Tags: javascript

I have a regex to remove the html tags to count my characters. Which is working fine.

```
<string_variable>.replaceAll("<(.|\n)*?>","").replaceAll("&nbsp;"," ").replaceAll("&amp;","&");

alert <string_variavle>.length()
```

But I need to add the 
 (New Line) to count my characters.

> ABC
> DEC

For example above ABC and DEC are 6 characters with 2 break lines it should be 9. As of now it is just counting with 6 characters.

Search for similar issue.
Tweaking my code

Comment: ABC and DEC are 6 characters with 2 break lines, Shouldn't it be 8, why 9 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can systematically replace all of your `\n` to a different char and then use the length:

```
const temp = myVar.replaceAll("\n", "a")
console.log(temp.length)
```

Comment: what if it is a Line break? Like this

<div>ABC<br /></div><div><br /></div><div>DEC<br /></div>

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = `
    <div>
      abc
    </div>
    <div>
      abc
    </div>`

console.log(countNewlines(str))

function countNewlines(input) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] === '\n') {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```